# Возвращение экрана в начало текста при нажатти кнопки "Скрыть"

Tags: javascript

Как мне сделать так, чтобы когда нажимаешь клавишу показать меньше текста, экран возвращался в начало текста? Код:

```
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    var show = document.getElementById("show");

    show.onclick = function(){
    if (content.className == "open"){
    content.className = "";
    show.innerHTML = "Показать больше"; 
    } 
    else {
      content.className = "open";
      show.innerHTML = "Скрыть";
    }}
```

Comment: Вы имеете виду скролл?

Comment: Да, скролл в начало текста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проскролить страницу к нужному месту можно следующим образом:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop = content.scrollTop
```

Этот код нужно вызвать сразу после закрития тестка.